# Implement Finger scan in android(5.0) application

Tags: android

As I found after google search we can implement finger scan authentication after Android(6.0). I want to implement it in Android 5.0.
but I didn't find any solution. how to implement that.

I have tried to install other application of finger scan supported on Android 5.0.2 and it works fine.

Can anyone help me please how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Before android 6 finger scan was supported only by some vendors for their phohes. You should check if vendor of your phone has some SDK and a documentation. For example, there is one for Samsung http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/pass

Comment: My device is micromax e455 with Android 5.0.2. there is no finger auth sdk of their.

Comment: @VinodJadhav is it this device? http://www.gsmarena.com/micromax_canvas_nitro_4g_e455-7665.php It seems to me that it don't even have a fingerprint scanner.